# Why is "-kai" in "Handelskai" pronounced "-ki"?

Tags: pronunciation, austrian

There is a street and U-Bahn station in Vienna called `Handelskai`. Over the speakers in subway and busses I always hear it pronounced like "Handelski". However, other "Kais" (eg. "Franz-Josefs-Kai") were pronounced "kai" / "kay". Why is this only word pronounced different?

Comment: Probably a glitch in the recording. I see no reason to pronounce it differently. Kudos for such an interesting observation, though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the voice of Vienna public transport has changed two years ago, I don't know which you are referring to, but you may convince yourself by listening to the old announcements of Franz Kaida (http://www.fpdwl.at/forum/downloads/ansagen/u-bahn/6-stationsansagen-linie-u6/index.html) that he didn't say "kee" (English pronunciation) but an elongated "kay" which may sound like "kee" in the ears of an English native speaker – or a Polish one, which I can't tell. If you're not referring to the "old" voice, the new one of Angela Schneider is even better trained and certainly didn't let wrongly slip an "ee".

You can get the answer why "Kai" is pronounced like the French "quai" from etymological sources like the *[Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK00274)*: "Kai" is, until today, often taken for a word of French origin and thus pronounced, although it is of Netherlandish origin ("Man findet in deutschem text häufig die franz. form, weil man das wort gewöhnlich für ein franz. hält, auch franz. ausspricht, schwerlich mit recht"). But this seems to be the case not only in Vienna or Austria, but also in several regions throughout Germany. Wherever the word has the French spelling outside French-speaking countries, of course, it is usually also pronounced that way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the audio recording seems to have been lost.

Answer (score 7):

In Vienna, *Kai* is pronounced [keː] instead of [kaɪ̯].

Comment: Could you please say something about the difference OP claims to hear? Are all other stations pronounced "atypically"?

Comment: I don't really know about that. Maybe it's just a speech computer that is unadapted.

Comment: No, not a computer. On the [official homepage of Wiener Linien](http://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal2/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66528/channelId/-48843), there is a link to a making-of video for the sounds. There is also a fan page where you can find the full audio files of the older versions used until a few yours ago

Comment: As far as I know Kai = riverbank in English and all those places are pronounced [ke:] in Vienna.

Comment: @AlKepp: Does the word have a different meaning in Austria than in Germany? In Germany, a "Kai" is not simply a riverbank, but a wharf; a stretch of a shoreline which has been fortified with a vertical wall to enable the landing of ships.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I am not Austrian language expert. Handelskai is the name of a street in Vienna, it goes many kilometers along the Danube river. And yes, there is a wharf there.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't pronounced differently, maybe the sound recording is different due to technical reasons. In Vienna, "Kai" is pronounced [ke:].

Till the end of the 19th century, most foreign words in Austrian German were French (or Latin or Yiddish, some were Italian and some from Slavic languages), not English, not Dutch. French was considered to be more noble, and English played no role at all.

The original spelling was "Handelsquai" from the French word "quai", see e.g. https://www.geschichtewiki.wien.gv.at/Handelskai
and therefore the "quai" was also pronounced French-like.

Comment: 'and therefore the "quai" was also pronounced French-like' - is *that* the reason for the pronunciation? I'm asking because in my impression, the "ai"/"ei" sound is *always* pronounced like something between 'ä' and 'e' by most speakers with Austrian pronunciation, no matter what word I'm looking at.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper : Yes, it is, you're right. In this case, the French origin of the word "quai" is the reason for today's pronunciation of "-kai" in Vienna.

Comment: Well ... do you have any references in support of that claim? I mean, anything that would convincingly overrule the factor that even the word spelt "Kai", which is pronounced [kai] by people from most parts of Germany, would be pronounced similar to [ke:] by people from Vienna, anyway?

Comment: I live in Vienna, Austria, and was also born here. :-) The reference has already been linked in my answer above from Jun 24, 2022.

Comment: The monophtongisation in Viennese dialect, which you might be talking about, is not a closed [e:], but an open [ɛ:].
So, the word "Kai" is pronounced [ke:] due to its French origin, but "Kaiser" is monophtongized pronounced [ˈkɛ:sa] in Viennese dialect, and [ˈkaɪzə] in official High German.

Comment: In general, for Viennese dialect, one can use
https://www.amazon.de/W%C3%B6rterbuch-Wienerischen-HAYMON-TASCHENBUCH-Sedlaczek/dp/3852188911

and 

https://www.amazon.de/Sprechen-Sie-Wienerisch-Adaxl-Zwutschkerl/dp/3800078198/

and there will appear also a new book
https://www.amazon.de/Wienerisch-Zwischen-leiwand-wuascht-Dialekte/dp/3411756918/

Comment: Thank you, the explicit confirmation that whoever observed the pronunciation of Handelskai like [e:] was aware of and consciouly distinguished it from the [ɛ:] in other ai/ei sounds of German words was what I was looking for.

Comment: OK, I understand your intentions. An online example of (acted) Viennese dialect is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4w0Nf7hxeSc
"Scheißhaus" (literally: "shitting house" or "house of shit") is pronounced [ˈʃɛ:shɔ:s] there at around 0:04. A High German pronunciation would have been [ˈʃaɪshaʊs] or something like that.
Viennese monophtongues (in place of High German diphtongues) are generally open and not closed. In Viennese dialect, we use closed vowels to mock Northern Germans. ;-)

Comment: In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4w0Nf7hxeSc there are quite many written "ei" pronounced [ɛ:]. The lyrics (in Higher German) is:
-Dankeschön!

-Hä... hä
Wenn Du nochmal sagst, dass meine Wohnung ein Scheißhaus ist, dann kannst Du gleich ausziehen! Gleich, gleich, gleich, gleich, gleich rutscht mir die Hand aus, hörst Du! Und wenn Du zehnmal verheiratet bist! Du kriegst eine Watsche, dass Dir 14 Tage lang der Schädel aufgeht!

-Schrei nicht so, mitten in der Nacht!

-Ich kann schreien, wann es mir passt, in meiner Wohnung, und wenn es mitten in der
Nacht ist! [...]

Comment: And here is a audio example from an Austrian private broadcast tv
https://youtu.be/XqDVSiVznAI?t=240
reporting on the terror event of Nov 02, 2020, in Vienna. At 4:00 you can hear "Franz-Josefs-Kai" with a closed [e:]. ("Ein vierzigjähriger Lokalbesitzer wird kurz vor dem Franz-Josef-Kai erschossen.")